# Grid system is perfectly working in PC but it doesn't work in Mobile - It show the same PC view on mobile

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Grid system is perfectly working in pc but it doesn't work in mobile.

it show the same pc view on mobile.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this code?

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="img/images.jpg" /></a> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
           <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/"><img src="img/download.png"/></a> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3  col-6">
           <a href="https://github.com"><img src="img/14.png" /></a></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
           <a href="https://www.instagram.com"><img src="img/images (1).jpg"  /> 
        </a>
        </d>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure the above code is enough to see the solution. Can you please include at least your meta tags?

Comment: Add the "`col-sm-x`" classes  to your `<div/>`'s (where x is the width /12 you would like)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this into your `<head>` code at the start of the document:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Hope this helps!